# Having issues converting simple text file parsing python script to c#

Tags: c#, python

Started learning python a while back and one of my first creations was a script I used to solve an ID check at work. I recently picked up c# and was looking to convert this script over to c# but have been having a lot of issues.

The script basically solves the 3 character pass phrase we are asked to verify by reading 3 pairs for the grid. For example it will ask for A3, B4, and D5. The Letters are columns and the numbers are the rows and each will have a random character corresponding to it. I think my main issue is I am trying to have the script work the exact way I have it working in python, whereas I am sure c# has a better way of calculating this. Also running into a TON of problems dealing with types and converting things to other types.

Here is the working Python Code: http://pastebin.com/qBtK9rXg

Here is what I have in C# so far (feel like I'm close but so far away): http://pastebin.com/MjbKsZfk

I guess the main question I have at this point is: if user input is string "A1", what would the best way be to have the program know that "A" was the first column? I have each line converted to a string array, then I was hoping to index the answer I need.

Comment: What specific problems are you are having?

Comment: Trying to mimic what I did in python I went the route trying to reference what I needed in dictionaries, hoping that C# dictionaries would do the trick.  Near the bottom when I try  int finalRow = rows[finalCol].ToString(); it tells me cannot convert from int to string.  This is because the second entry in the first dictionary are integers I believe. I tried just setting final row to int type but still not working